# Glimpse ASP.Net funcionando com Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, dapper

Acabei de ver um conteúdo em que eu estudava sobre performance e otimização nas aplicações ASP.Net. Me apresentaram uma ferramenta de diagnóstico que se chama `Glimpse`.

O Funcionamento da ferramenta é perfeito, faz a medição dos tempos de execução das requisições ajax, tempo das consultas SQL e o comando das consultas SQL executadas diretamente no banco de dados, resumindo, um diagnóstico completo, porém as consultas só funcionam se forem feitas através do `Entity Framework`.

Tentando trazer essa realidade pro meu ambiente de trabalho, me deparei com a divergência que uso o `Dapper` e ele só funciona pro `EF`.

Minha dúvida então é se seria possível que tal ferramenta funcionasse com `Dapper`? Haveria outra ferramenta de diagnóstico que traga informações ricas como essas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, eu acabei utilizando o `LightHouse` do Google, acabou atendendo minhas espectativas. Abaixo um pouco mais sobre o LightHouse que é basicamente uma ferramenta de diagnóstico também

> O `Lighthouse` é uma ferramenta automatizada de código aberto que aprimora a qualidade de apps da Web. Ele pode ser executado como extensão do Chrome ou na linha de comando. Informe ao Lighthouse um URL que você quer auditar. Ele executará uma série de testes na página e gerará um relatório sobre o desempenho da página. Nesse relatório, você poderá usar os testes que apresentaram falha como indicadores do que pode ser feito para aprimorar o aplicativo.

Ajudou bastante na questão de performance / otimização e gargalos.